# view underling functions as ordered pairs from sagemath lambda statement

Tags: python, lambda, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, sage

In sagemath I am using the following to successfully view the set of all functional digraphs on a set of size n, for example, for n = 3

```
property= lambda G: all(G.out_degree(v) <= 1 for v in G)
L = filter(property, digraphs(3))
#M=list(digraphs(3))
#len(M)
len(L)
graphs_list.show_graphs(L)
```

[Attached is the example input/output for n = 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTQTH.png)

I would like to see the underlying functions. I.e., suppose the set of size 3 is {a,b,c}, then I would like to find a way to output the corresponding seven functions (one for each diagram in the output). I,e. something like

```
f1 = {(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)}, f2 = {(a,b),(b,b),(c,c)}, ... , f7 = {(a,a),(b,a),(c,a)}
```

More generally I suppose I'm wondering if the code is (via sage (under-the-hood)) doing this or simply pulling in a graph theoretic library in which the actual "functions" are obscured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Sage numbers the vertices `0`, `1`, `2` rather than `a`, `b`, `c`.

This does almost what you want:

```
sage: for g in L:
....:     print g.edges(labels=False)
....:
[]
[(0, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

This gets closer to your desired output.

```
sage: def im(g, v):
....:     n = g.neighbors(v)
....:     return v if not n else n[0]
....: 
sage: for g in L:
....:     print('{' + ','.join(['({},{})'.format(v, im(g, v)) for v in g.vertices()]) + '}')
....:     
{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)}
{(0,1),(1,0),(2,2)}
{(0,1),(1,0),(2,2)}
{(0,1),(1,0),(2,1)}
{(0,1),(1,0),(2,0)}
{(0,1),(1,0),(2,1)}
{(0,1),(1,0),(2,1)}
```

Regarding what Sage is doing under the hood, explore
the source code and let us know what you found.

Notice however that you obtained the list of functional digraphs
by filtering the list of all digraphs, so Sage is likely not using
the underlying functions for those digraphs.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and your explanation helps understand. I'll explore the source. Thanks again!